# Iterating parsed json array of arrays

Tags: php, json, titanium, appcelerator

I'm retrieving json from php to the mobile, the code is as follow

```
$a = array('name'=>'pop', 'age'=>'32', 'kids'=>array('tim', 'john') );
echo json_encode($a);
```

in the mobile I recieve the data fine, but upon parsing json and trying to access the "kids" elements using its keys it gives me an error. Here is the mobile code:

```
var json = this.responseText;  
var response = JSON.parse(json);
alert(response.kids[0]);
```

The error :

[image]

this also occurs when trying to get "kids.length".. any help?

Comment: You have a typo there: `'name'='pop'` should be `'name'=>'pop'`

Comment: That's the only thing I see too, other than that response.kids[0] should work.

Comment: please try 'alert(JSON.stringify(response));' and check what it alerts.

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP array is not valid.

```
$a = array('name'='pop', 'age'=>'32', 'kids'=>array('tim', 'john') );
```

Should be:

```
$a = array('name' => 'pop', 'age'=>'32', 'kids' => array('tim', 'john') );
```

Comment: Copy and paste your JSON string.